# Run PHP in Linux Command Line

Tags: php, linux, command-line, centos, command-line-interface

I wrote a test file named `phpinfo.php` which path in [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) is  `/var/www/html/phpinfo.php`. There is no browser, is there a way to run the file and see the output?

Comment: `$ curl localhost/phpinfo.php`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

```
 - php /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
 - curl http://localhost/phpinfo.php
```

The first runs the script from commandline, the second fetches it from the webserver (this assumes you've configured it correctly)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run it directly on the command line (which seems unlikely as you have placed the file in the webroot):

```
php /path/to/script.php
```

If you want to access it through the webserver then you need to make sure the server is configured to run PHP scripts, and then make an HTTP request. Using a web browser is the easiest way to do this. Either install one or use one on another machine with network access to the server.

Comment: What shows it cannot open the file? What precise error message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in the output of `phpinfo()` you can see the same information from the command line with:

```
php -i
```

This prints it in a console-friendly format, rather than in styled HTML as `phpinfo()` displays.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use.

```
php /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You would usually do something like this:

`php /var/www/html/phpinfo.php`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the command-line:

```
php /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```